# How to integrate Google Calender in react native?

Tags: react-native, google-calendar-api

How to make an event in the user's google calendar through my app which is in react native?

Comment: Ciao, just a suggestion: don't completely change your question. Edit it requiring more info. If for example you made a mistake and you want change your question, cancel it and make another question.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you can:

1. Use [react-native-add-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-add-calendar-event) to create an event on your device calendar.
2. Download google calendar app in your device.

When you open google calendar app, all of your events will be synced with your device calendar.

Comment: I have to deeply integrate google calender with my react native app. I am stuck in getting OAuth procedure of Google Calendar.

Comment: Ciao, lets say you want to download your calendar list and already retrieved an accessToken, call should be: `getUsersCalendarList = async (accessToken) => {
    let calendarsList = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/calenda/v3/users/me/calendarList', {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ${accessToken}'},
    });
    return calendarsList.json();
}`. note that Bearer ${accessToken} must be between backtick (if I put backtick here text will be formatted as code).